# alsamixer does not change Sound Volume

Tags: linux, alsa, usb-audio

`alsamixer` doesn't change the real sound volume of my USB sound card (though the dials move okay)

```
# uname -a
Linux RPN 2.6.28.10-rpn7.2 #1 SMP Tue Jun 7 07:23:01 EDT 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

# cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.18rc3.

# dpkg -l | grep alsa
ii alsa-base 1.0.17.dfsg-4 ALSA driver configuration files
ii alsa-oss 1.0.15-1 ALSA wrapper for OSS applications
ii alsa-utils 1.0.16-2 ALSA utilities

# cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [default ]: USB-Audio - USB AUDIO
USB AUDIO at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1, full speed
1 [default_1 ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Sound Device at usb-0000:00:1d

# lsusb
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc.
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1631:5000 Good Way Technology
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1130:f211 Tenx Technology, Inc. TP6911 Audio Headset
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0755:2626 Aureal Semiconductor
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Same issue here. I guess that soundcard is just piece of crap... I've buyed few similar cards from DX (ordered under same SKU at different times). One with yellow led is crap, one with green led is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command

```
alsamixer -c 1
```

The above command will control the C-Media card, listed in `/proc/asound/cards`, which I am assuming is the one you want to control.